# How can I retrieve information from nested joins in Apostrophe CMS?

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'd like to know how to fetch data from joins inside joins.

For instance: I have a **category-widgets** that must get the information of all of the **lessons** related to that chosen category (teacher, description, and other infos - that are also joins in the **lesson** piece).

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-widgets',
  label: 'Categories',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: '_category',
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: 'category',
      label: 'Categories',
      withJoins: ['_lesson'],
    }
  ]
};
```

The code above is the index.js of the **category-widgets**. And by using the `withJoins` I can fetch information about that lesson.

The thing is **lesson** itself is made mainly of information in joins:

```
module.exports = {
  extend: 'apostrophe-pieces',
  name: 'lesson',
  label: 'Lesson',
  pluralLabel: 'Lessons',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: '_teacher',
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: 'teacher',
      label: 'Teacher(s)',
    },
    {
      name: '_pill',
      type: 'joinByArray',
      withType: 'pill',
      label: 'Pills of knowledge that make the lesson.',
    },
  ]
};
```

My question is towards how can I access the data inside `_teacher` and
`_pill` in the **widget.html** of **category-widgets**.

> `apos.log(data.widget._category._lesson)` outputs the right data about the lesson.
>
> But when trying to fetch data from inside a join as such: `apos.log(data.widget._category._lesson._teacher[0])` outputs **undefined**.

Answer (score 0):

`withJoins: [ '_lesson._teacher', '_lesson._pill' ]` will do it. withJoins supports dot paths.